# PHP split string and transform parts into links

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have this possible strings in my DB:

```
"#111111 opened";
"#111111 opened";
"Opened ticket #111111";
"Opened ticket #111111 something else.";
"Opened ticket #111111 and ticket #222222";
"Opened ticket #111111 and ticket #222222 something else.";
```

I'm trying to change that string to include links like this:

```
Opened ticket <a href="http://siteOfTickets.com/ticket/111111" target="_blank">#111111</a> and ticket <a href="http://siteOfTickets.com/ticket/222222" target="_blank">#222222</a> something else.
```

I split the string by doing this:

```
$arrary1 = preg_split("/#[0-9]{6}/", $report->obs);
preg_match_all('/#[0-9]{6}/', $report->obs, $array2);
```

Now i'm struggling to complete this. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use preg_replace:

```
$str = preg_replace('/#(\d{6})\b/', 
       '<a href="http://siteOfTickets.com/ticket/$1" target="_blank">#$1</a> ',
        $report->obs);
```

Comment: Made a change in the regex code to '/#(\d{6})/' to accept situacions like '#111111e' that could happen, but it works. Thanks!